# full screen hook?

Tags: hooks, fullscreen

Is there a way to add a hook for when emacs goes full screen? I'd like to set slightly different transparency for the frame when in fullscreen but there seems to be no easy way for that.

What I would want is for emacs to detect it is now in fullscreen and subsequently change its transparency.

Answer (score 4):

The only hook I know of that might help is `window-size-change-functions`.

Code such as this, for example (replace the `message` call by whatever you want done:

```lisp
(defun foo (frame)
  (let ((fullscreen  (frame-parameter frame 'fullscreen)))
    (when (memq fullscreen '(fullscreen fullboth))
      (message "Do what you want here."))))

(add-hook 'window-size-change-functions 'foo)
```

This hook runs each time there is a change in any window size the hook functions are invoked.  `C-h v` says:

> Functions called during redisplay, if window sizes have changed.
> The value should be a list of functions that take one argument.
> During the first part of redisplay, for each frame, if any of its windows
> have changed size since the last redisplay, or have been split or deleted,
> all the functions in the list are called, with the frame as argument.
> If redisplay decides to resize the minibuffer window, it calls these
> functions on behalf of that as well.

You can instead advise a function, such as `toggle-frame-fullscreen` (bound to `<f11>`), that makes the frame fullscreen.

---

Emacs hooks and such advice will *not*, however, be called when you use window-manager artifacts, such as a maximize/restore icon/button.

It's possible to invoke Elisp code when *some* window-manager events, such as clicking the iconify/minimize icon/button.  You do that using keymap `special-event-map`.

For example, to do something different from iconifying when you click the iconify/minimize button, you can do this:

```lisp
(define-key special-event-map [iconify-frame] 'my-frame-action)
```

I take advantage of that, optionally, in my library [`thumb-frm.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?search=%22thumb-frm%5c.el%22), for example -- [Fisheye With Thumbs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FisheyeWithThumbs).

(Be aware of this fact/feature, which is true of any binding on
keymap `special-event-map`: The event interrupts any key sequence
in progress, to invoke its command, and then the key sequence as a
whole is processed, ignoring the special event.)

However, as far as I can tell, the maximize/restore icon/button is *not* associated by Emacs with a special event. (Iconify/minimize is, but maximize is not.) So I don't see a way to make the window-manager maximize/restore button invoke Elisp code. Maybe someone else has some suggestion about this.

Comment: I have tried using the code for `window-size-change-functions` you provided and it first it looked like it worked just the way I intended it to work but then it occurred to me that switching buffer triggered the function (`foo` here) to work as if it was the fullscreen and after some further tests it's the ivy buffer that does that -- eg `M-x` also triggers the function to execute as if the frame were in fullscreen

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. If it's a new question (I'm guessing it is), please submit that separately. If it's a clarification of this question, please edit the question.

Comment: My initial intention was to have a "fullscreen hook" that would simply change window's transparency each time I resize it depending on whether it is fullscreened or not. I have tried using your code with the `window-size-change-functions` and it does detect entering fullscreen but also each time I use commands that use `ivy` completion it seems like emacs also calls the function I've added as if the window was fullscreen. So: I resize the frame -- transparency changes as I wanted. But also: I call eg `M-x` -- it changes as well. I hope that's more clear (I think it is still the same question)

Comment: See the definition of that hook - yes, it's run for every window size change. Your hook function for it should choose to do nothing for the cases you're not interested in.

Comment: @ggegoge Bear in mind that what Emacs calls a `window` is *not* the same thing that an operating system/window manager calls a "window"; that's called a `frame` in Emacs. An Emacs `window` is what would be called a "pane" elsewhere. Hope that's clarifying not confusing. See `(info "(emacs) Windows")` and `(info "(emacs) Frames")`.